# authorize roles in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a web api application with authentication using asp.net for backend and storing the data in SQL server. I created an ApplicationUser class and now I wanna add some roles for the users, but I'm a noobie in .net. For Registration and Authentication I am using the basic implemented classes created by the project.

What I've done so far for roles is to add the roles in the database and then I added this in Startup.cs class:

```
 services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

And in the Register.cs class I added a new field for role:

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Role")]
    public string Role { get; set; }
```

And this commands in OnPostAsync method from the same class to create the user and to add the role to it:

```
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { 
                    UserName = Input.Email, 
                    Email = Input.Email, 
                    FirstName = Input.FirstName, 
                    LastName = Input.LastName, 
                    EmailConfirmed = true
            };

                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, Input.Role);
```

After this, when I registered in the app the AspNetUserRoles table was filled in with userId and roleId, but when I added the [Authorize] tag to a method in Controller I got the 401Unauthorized response.

This is the method from the Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Customer")]
        [Route("ForCustomerAndSupplier")]
        public UserDTO GetUserInfo()
        {
            var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier); // id of the logged in user
            return _userService.GetUserInfo(userId);
        }
```

Should I add something in Login class to somehow map the user to the role?

Comment: Did you add **app.UseAuthentication();** in Configure method of Startup.cs class?

Comment: Yes. I added also app.UserAuthorization();

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look at it and everything seems in order. You may want to try a few things below:

(1) Since you manually created the 'Role' in the database, double-check the name to ensure it's the same case, no spaces etc.
(2) Remove the Authorize attribute and set a breakpoint on the GetUserInfo method to see if you get the result.
(3) In Startup.cs, replace the code below with the snippet I typed below

**services.AddDefaultIdentity(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddRoles()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores();**

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(c => c.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```